# What does "precompile standard library" option mean in python installation?

Tags: python, python3

I am trying to understand different options in Python3 installation. What does the "Precompile Standard library" option mean in the Custom Python installation and why should it be enabled or left deselected by default?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you import a python library and it doesn't have a corresponding `.pyc` file (or it's out of date compared to the source), [python will "compile" new bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998215/120999). [It appears](https://bugs.python.org/issue25102#msg250686) that this option simply does that for everything in the standard library so that it doesn't have to be done the first time you import them.

As to why it's not the default, I don't know; I'd *guess* it's because it has very little effect and some people don't want to spend the work on that for libraries they'll never use.